# Inject an error message to errors object

Tags: laravel-4

Is there a way to inject an error message so we can show it on a view with `$errors` instance, on a redirection?

```
$errors->all(); // e.g. to have it here
```

Which I tried:

```
return Redirect::to('dashboard')
                    ->with('errors', 'Custom error');
```

But actually will throw an error:

```
Call to a member function all() on a non-object
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example doesn't work since you're passing just a variable instead of an object.

If you want to add your own custom error message to other validation errors, you can use the `add()` method of `Illuminate\Support\MessageBag` class (since validation errors are returned as an instance of this class):

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    $errors = $validator->messages();
    $errors->add('Error', 'Custom Error');

    return Redirect::to('dashboard')->withErrors($errors);
}
```

Now your custom message should display alongside other validation errors.

Answer (score 1):

### Simple, one line solution

While what [kajetrons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2059483/kajetons) [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23469162/1494454) is completely true, it is unnecessary to create a validator if you just want to return an error message through the `$errors` object. This can be written more simply in one line:

```
return Redirect::to('dashboard')->withErrors(new \Illuminate\Support\MessageBag(['Custom error']));
```